# 0.0038031 ACPI: Unable to load the System Description Tables

Tags: system-installation

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu 15.04 on my Acer Aspre E5-573 running on Intel i5 5th gen with 500gb harddisk 4gb ram and Intel HD Graphics 5500 I get this error

> 0.0038031 ACPI: Unable to load the System Description Tables

Please tell me how to install it? I'm not even remotely interested using Windows but I have to. Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not only yours. It is with everyone who is using BIOS v1.25. <s>You need to downgrade your BIOS. I too was suffering from this problem and did the following:</s>

Since 2015-12-28 no need to downgrade any more, just upgrade your bios (download, double click & restart)! I've switched from 1.25 to version 1.31 (2015/12/23) and it fixed this problem.

Go to your region's Acer support website page.

Search by Product Model:
Aspire E5-573x (Where x stands for your specific model)

Select the right OS and download a bios. In my case I downloaded 1.15.

Run the `ZRT_115.exe`.

It will fail.
But before you close the installer, go to `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\`

Search for a folder (random letters).tmp

There should be a `H2OFFT-W.exe` and `zrt.rd` file in there.
Just copy this folder and close the failing install.

In that copied folder, edit the `platform.ini` file.

Before:

```
Quote:
[BIOSVersionFormat]
;[nb4-version] +
BIOSVFEnable=1
VersionFormat=XN.NN
```

After:

```
Quote:
[BIOSVersionFormat]
;[nb4-version] +
BIOSVFEnable=1
VersionFormat=XN.DD
```

The `VersionFormat` value now has `XN.DD` instead of `XN.NN`. This will ignore the fact that 1.25 -> 1.15 is a downgrade.

Prepare for a reboot, *i.e.* close unnecessary applications. Because it'll happen automatically after running the installer.

Run `H2OFFT-W.exe`.
Upon reboot, you'll see a bios installing progress bar.
After that is done, press F2 during startup to get to bios. The version should now be 1.15.

Now you will be able to installed any GNU/Linux distro of your choice.

Don't forget to up vote and accept the answer!

Comment: Confirmation that this worked great for another E5-573 (E5-573G, technically, if that makes any difference). Couldn't boot any Linux distro's live CD or flash drive before, now working like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. My goal was to run Clonezilla to image the disk from a new machine (Aspire E 15 E5-573-37V5) before first booting Windows, or removing the drive (potentially voiding the warranty); thus a workaround requiring Windows was a no-no. I tried several Linux distros, including old ones, 32-bit.. without any success. I hate this bug (of the bios) and wish the kernel, or whatever, had a workaround.

Comment: I am using version 1.36 and this works fine on the 573